# Add to (not overwrite) a global variable from a Loop PHP

Tags: php

I'm working on a php script that adds up points from voting using the borda count. I've got files read, data set up, but I'm struggling to set up a way to put an individuals points into their array. Right now I have an array of candidates, and an array of votes. I'm attempting to add up the votes and put them inside of the candidate array. The first number in each vote index responds to the first candidate, and so on. I have the program calculating the vote points correctly, but I can't get them to add together so I have the final number once it finishes.

edit: This script is also supposed to be scalable, meaning if I have 6 candidates, rather than 4, it will work. If there's something that jumps out at the reader saying it won't work, please let me know

```
<?php
$file = $argv[1];

$inputFile = fopen($file,"r");

$candidates = fgets($inputFile);
$candidates = str_replace(' ','',$candidates);
echo $candidates;
$candidates = explode(',',$candidates);
print_r($candidates);
$numCandidates = count($candidates);
echo "The number of candidates is: " . $numCandidates. "\n";
/**
$testFile = file_get_contents("$argv[1]");
$testFile = explode('\n',$testFile);
print_r($testFile);
*/

while (!feof($inputFile)){
    $votes[] = trim(fgets($inputFile),"\n");
}

unset($votes[count($votes)-1]);
//$votes = trim("\n",$votes);
//$votes = explode(',',$votes);
print_r($votes);


for ($i = 0; $i<count($votes); $i++){
    $votes[$i] = str_replace(',','',$votes[$i]);
}
print_r($votes);
/**
for($x = 0;$x<count($candidates);$x++){
$z = 0;

for($y = 0;$y<count($votes);$y++){
$candidates[$x][$y] = $votes[$y][$z];
}
print_r($candidates[0]);
$z++;
}
*/
for ($x = 0; $x<count($votes);$x++){
    global $candidates;
    for ($y=0; $y<count($candidates);$y++){
        $candidates[$y][0]= (($numCandidates + 1)-$votes[$x][$y]);
        echo "\nThe value of candidate $y is " . $candidates[$y][0];
    }
}

?>
```

This is where I'm attempting to add to the amount, but it just keeps overwriting.

```
for ($x = 0; $x<count($votes);$x++){
    global $candidates;
    for ($y=0; $y<count($candidates);$y++){
        $candidates[$y][0]= (($numCandidates + 1)-$votes[$x][$y]);
        echo "\nThe value of candidate $y is " . $candidates[$y][0];
    }
}
```

Edit: When I attempt to use `+=` rather than = in

```
$candidates[$y][0] = (($numCandidates + 1)-$votes[$x][$y]);
```

I get an error saying "can't use assign-op operators with overloaded objects nor string offsets"

Comment: Your `global $candidates` is 100% redundant since you're doing everything in the global scope.  Moreover, you should never use `global` to begin with.  Beyond that, can you clarify how your candidate and vote arrays are set up?  What you're trying to do with them, what's actually happening, etc.?  It's difficult to see without a code example of their structure and an output example.

Comment: THe candidate array is simple an array holding the names of the Candidates that I'm reading from a file. Under the names in the file are a series of numbers representing the vote that they got. Those are stored in votes. From there, I'm attempted to calculate the number of points based on the number in vote, and put in inside of the candidates name, so it would be a 2d array.

Comment: What is the purpose of `[0]` in `$candidates[$y][0]`? You can assign a value to an array so candidate $y has a percentage / count of `<calculated value>`.

Comment: The purpose of [0] is to put the vote points under the name. I'm going to have to print it out, so I just have it set up to where candidates[y] is a string, and candidates[y][0] would be the points they have

Comment: I'm still having a hard time visualizing what you want to do.  You should add an example of how your file is structured and how you want your array(s) to be structured to your question for clarity's sake.  Remember: we're not sitting in the room with you, so what you think is obvious to others might not actually be obvious

Answer (score 2):

```
$candidates[$y][0] = (($numCandidates + 1)-$votes[$x][$y]);
```

That `=` should be `+=` so that your loop keeps adding the value, instead of overwriting the existing value on every iteration.

```
$candidates[$y][0] += (($numCandidates + 1)-$votes[$x][$y]);
```

Comment: When I attempt to do this, I get an error saying that I can't use assign-op operators with overloaded objects nor string offsets.

Comment: What is the value of `(($numCandidates + 1)-$votes[$x][$y])` in any example case?

Comment: Any value between 1 and 4. There are 4 candidates (4+1) then the value in $votes[$x][$y] is anything between 1-4. So the max value is 4+1-1 = 4, and the min value is 4+1-4 = 1

edit: This will change with new input, but the min value will always be 1. The max value will rise to however many candidates there are

Comment: Ok then the initial value of candidates[$y][0] is a string. You need to initialize it as a number.